# drag-and-drop problem in a Tilelist using an ItemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, tilelist

in my flex application, I created a Tilelist. In this Tilelist, I am using an ItemRenderer to create a box consisting of an image and an VSlider in each tile.

The tile need to be dragable when you click on the image, but not dragable when you slide the slider. How can I achieve this ? I have been scratching my head searching on Google for one day and I have really no idea.

I look forward to your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem, however it may not be the best one.

Using this :

```
        public var overImage:Boolean = false;

        public function checkAllow(evt:DragEvent):void {

            if(overImage == false)
            {
                evt.preventDefault()
            }
        }

        public function isOverImage():void {
            overImage = true;
        }

        public function isOutImage():void {
            overImage = false;
        }
```

I call those functions like this :

On my image component

```
mouseOver="outerDocument.isOverImage()" mouseOut="outerDocument.isOutImage()"
```

And for my tilelist I did this

```
Tiles.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_START, checkAllow);
```

Hope it helps some people.

Answer (score 0):

```
            if(event.target is ScrollThumb )
        {
            return;
        }
```

problem solved by returning the scrollThumb property of sroller in imageDragStart method...

BackGround:My TileList is provided with  mouseDown ="event.currentTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, imageDragStart )";

which was effecting complete TileList along with scroller ,

This above was the temp fix, but expecting experts suggestions.

Basically this is for Native application (AIR), used NativeDragStart. but am forced to use mouseDown over my TileList to invoke imageStartDrag() method of mine....